# Threadを使うと、配列の順番が変わる?

Tags: python

threading.Thread()を使っていて、問題がでたので、質問させていただきます。
次のシンプルな、配列をforループさせてprintするスクリプトがあります。
worker()をそのまま実行すると、配列の0番目から順にprintされますが、
Thread(target=worker)で実行すると逆順に出力されます。
(ちなみに、配列をrange(5000)とかにすると、順番がぐちゃぐちゃになる場合もあります。(毎回確実ではない))

```
from threading import Thread

def worker():
    nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
    for n in nums:
        print n

# これは、printの順番は、1=>11
worker()


# これだと、printの順番が11=>1になってしまう
t = Thread(target=worker)
t.start()
```

何か設定に問題があるのでしょうか。
Thread特有の仕様でしょうか?

環境はwindows10, Python2.7です。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: Windows10、Python2.7.13、Spyder3.2.3 で試しましたが、その現象は再現できませんでした。

Comment: @TatsuyaNakamori `print` する度に `sys.stdout.flush()` でフラッシュしてもバラバラに出力されますか？

Comment: 逆順とは11,10,9,...1ですか？ちょっと考えられませんね。逆順に出力されているなら、結果を載せてください。worker()の出力はバッファされるので、その出力が完了する前にスレッドが動き出して、worker()の出力とスレッドからの出力が混ざる可能性がありますが、それが逆順に見えているだけでは？printの代わりにlogging.infoで出力すると順番通りに出ます。loggingモジュールは複数スレッドから書き込んでも安全な作りになっているので。

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん
sys.stdout.flush()はprint 文の次の行に書けば大丈夫でしょうか。
print 文の次の行に書いてみましたが、結果は同じでした。

Comment: @KenjiNoguchiさん
logging.infoで出力すると、正しく順番に出力されました！
という事は、表示の問題で、内部はちゃんと動いていたんですね、、

シンプルなスクリプトで結果がおかしなことになっていたので、テンパっていました。。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

logging.infoで出力すると、正しく順番に出力されました。

---

<sup>この投稿は @Tatsuya Nakamori さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/37895/#comment38149_37895)などを元に編集し、[コミュニティWiki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1583)として投稿しました。</sup>